# Locking an Entire Table in Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

MySQL has a concept of [Locking an Entire Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) that I am trying to invoke within Eloquent. It is my understanding that Eloquent provides [a lockForUpdate function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#pessimistic-locking) that locks all records for a given select query. However, I am running into a large number of deadlock errors from running that command on an entire table For Example

```
DB::table('users')->lockForUpdate()->get();
```

My suspicion is that different sessions are calling the lockForUpdate function and locking the rows in a different order, hence the frequent deadlocks. However, my feeling is that considering we need to lock every row in the table anyway perhaps relying on the lockForUpdate function is the wrong way to go about things.

Does anyone know of a better way of handling the situation that is as convienent as calling lockForUpdate? I understand that we could just call raw SQL to lock and unlock the table as needed, but it seems very prone to error considering we'll need to remember to unlock the table at the end of every transaction, so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You can always extend Larave's db class and simply overwrite the transaction function and add the raw sql at the end. Seems a decent solution for your needs.

Comment: Locking for update is nicely abstracted across all database types that eloquent supports, so a solution that does the same for whole tables would be good. A further note, the example above will select all the rows in the users table. That data will be retrieved in the `get()`, into a collection in memory, so probably not ideal if the table is large. It will also do a `select *` by default, so we are talking about ALL columns in the users table. Even if garbage collection throws the data away by not assigning it, it still lived and could blow memory limits.